# How to use django-cumulus for serving Static files?

Tags: django, rackspace-cloud, django-staticfiles

I'm trying to use [django-cumulus](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus/) for serving files off Rackspace CloudFiles. I'm currently only trying it on my local dev server, using Django 1.4.2.

I can use cumulus's `syncstatic` management command to upload all my static assets successfully, but I can't seem to display them on my site with the same settings.

If my relevant settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
CUMULUS = {
    'USERNAME': 'myusername',
    'API_KEY': 'myapikey',
    'CONTAINER': 'mycontainername',
    'STATIC_CONTAINER': 'mycontainername',
}
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cumulus.storage.CloudFilesStaticStorage'
```

then when I run `syncstatic` all my apps' static files are uploaded into `/mycontainername/static/`, as I'd expect. But when I load a page in admin it ignores `STATIC_URL` and tries to serve assets from URLs like `http://uniquekey....r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/path/to/file.css` rather than `http://uniquekey....r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/static/path/to/file.css`.

Also, I can't see how to have my public (non-admin) pages use the static files on CloudFiles, rather than serving them from a local `/static/` directory.

Have I missed some crucial setting, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What i did was to

git clone https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus.git

edit context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings

from cumulus.storage import CloudFilesStorage

def cdn_url(request):
    """
    A context processor to expose the full cdn url in templates.

    """
    cloudfiles_storage = CloudFilesStorage()
    static_url = '/'
    container_url = cloudfiles_storage._get_container_url()
    cdn_url = container_url + static_url

    print {'CDN_URL': cdn_url}

    return {'CDN_URL': cdn_url}
```

Once you are done, install it with sudo python setup.py install

Do note that context_processors.py from django cumulus is actually quite slow

Comment: Thanks amdstorm. Presumably you could get the `static_url` from `settings` instead of hard-coding it. And I'm not sure if you meant to leave the print statement in there :)

Comment: Didnt meant to leave the print statement there! sorry!

Comment: i realized when you compile the static asset, the static url is not used, thats why i used it as a /, bad variable naming my bad